# Enzyme Adaptor Error - Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to use Enzyme to test my React application and I'm coming across this error. I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere else and can't figure it out.

Here is the stack trace:

```
 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
        at hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)

      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/react-shallow-renderer/cjs/react-shallow-renderer.js:54:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/react-shallow-renderer/index.js:3:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/react-test-renderer/shallow.js:3:18)
```

Here is the code from my test which is causing it.

```
 const Enzyme = require('enzyme');
 const Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-15');

 Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

..... rest of test file
```

Dependencies from package.json

```
 "react": "15.6.0",
 "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
 "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.4.3",
```

Comment: what react version are you using?

Comment: @jkpark I am using React 15.6.0